# iOS - Quartz drawing issue with parent/child views

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

**Scenario**

I have two views. One is the "parent" view which contains a "child" view that does the drawing. I refer to the child as QuartzView in the code to follow. QuartzView knows how to draw a square to it's own context.

**Issue**

When I tell the QuartzView on it's `self` to draw a square it does so as expected. When I use the parent view to tell QuartsView to draw a square on it's `self` it draws the square in the lower left corner of the screen at about 1/5 the expected size.

**Question**

I assume there's some parent/child or context issues here but I'm not sure what they are. How can I get both squares to draw in the exact same place at the exact same size?

## Parent `ViewController`

```
- (void)drawASquare {

    // this code draws the "goofy" square that is smaller and off in the bottom left corner
    x = qv.frame.size.width / 2;
    y = qv.frame.size.height / 2;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(x, y);
    [qv drawRectWithCenter:center andWidth:50 andHeight:50 andFillColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

}
```

## Child `QuartzView`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.5];

    // this code draws a square as expected
    float w = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    float h = self.frame.size.height / 2;
    color = [UIColor blueColor];
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(w, h);
    [self drawRectWithCenter:center andWidth:20 andHeight:20 andFillColor:color];
}

- (void)drawRectWithCenter:(CGPoint)center andWidth:(float)w andHeight:(float)h andFillColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(self.context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(self.context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(center.x - w / 2, center.x - w / 2, w, h);

    CGContextFillRect(self.context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokeRect(self.context, rectangle);
}
```

*Note*

- The opacities are the same for both squares
- I turned off "Autoresize subviews" with no noticeable difference
- `view.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];` has not helped

## Edit

I'm noticing that the x/y values of the square when drawn the parent starting from the bottom left as 0,0 whereas normally 0,0 would be the top left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is only valid inside the `drawRect` method. You can not and must not use that context in any other method. So the `self.context` property should just be a local variable.

In the `drawRectWithCenter` method, you should store all of the parameters in properties, and then request a view update with `[self setNeedsDisplay]`. That way, the framework will call `drawRect` with the new information. The `drawRectWithCenter` method should look something like this

```
- (void)drawRectWithCenter:(CGPoint)center andWidth:(float)w andHeight:(float)h andFillColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.showCenter = center;
    self.showWidth = w;
    self.showHeight = h;
    self.showFillColor = color;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And of course, the `drawRect` function needs to take that information, and do the appropriate drawing.

Comment: This is a good point that didn't mention explicitly -- don't try to store and reuse the graphics context.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer isn't true in general but close enough for the sake of this question. There are other valid places where `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` can be valid. But the OP isn't using any of those situations.

Comment: @rmaddy Fair enough. It's kind of like saying that you can't take the square root of a negative number. Eventually, the student is prepared to understand more advanced concepts, but initially it's best to keep it simple.

Comment: It felt wrong assigning the context to a member in the first place and now I see that was my issue. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume there's some parent/child or context issues here but I'm not sure what they are. How can I get both squares to draw in the exact same place at the exact same size?

You normally don't need to worry about the graphics context in your `-drawRect:` method because Cocoa Touch will set up the context for you before calling `-drawRect:`. But your `-drawASquare` method in the view controller calls `-drawRectWithCenter:...` to draw outside the normal drawing process, so the context isn't set up for your view. You should really have the view do its drawing in `-drawRect:`. If your view controller wants to make the view redraw, it should call `-setNeedsDisplay`, like:

```
[qv setNeedsDisplay];
```

That will add the view to the drawing list, and the graphics system will set up the graphics context and call the view's `-drawRect:` for you.

> I'm noticing that the x/y values of the square when drawn the parent starting from the bottom left as 0,0 whereas normally 0,0 would be the top left.

UIKit and Core Animation use an upper left origin, but Core Graphics (a.k.a. Quartz) normally uses a lower left origin. The docs say:

[*The default coordinate system used by Core Graphics framework is LLO-based.*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

Comment: That is certainly new information but it only gets me so far. Because the same method from a single View is used both times, why is one square drawn to UIKit while the other is drawn to Quartz?

Comment: @Jacksonkr Because the context is only set up when `-drawRect:` is called. I hit the submit button a little early, have updated my answer. See above.